# OpenSSL CSR signing not including Locality

Tags: openssl

I am trying to sign a CSR generated with:

```
openssl req -new -key private/web.key.pem -sha256 \
  -extensions v3_ca -out certs/web.csr.pem \
  -subj "/C=DE/ST=Example State/L=Exmaple City/O=Example Org/OU=Example Org Unit/CN=example.com/emailAddress=foo@example.com"
```

When I check the CSR with a

```
openssl req -in certs/web.csr.pem -text -noout
```

the Locality shows up (there's a L=Example City visible). However, when I attempt to sign the CSR with

```
openssl ca -days 365 -keyfile private/ca.key.pem \
  -cert certs/ca.cert.pem -extensions v3_ca -md sha256 \
  -in certs/web.csr.pem -out certs/web.cert.pem
```

There is no Localty/City included in the subject, but it is visible in "DirName" in the X509v3 extension. I am pretty sure I am missing something obvious here, but I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is easy. I missed the `localityName` in my policy and obviously it won't get included then. This is a working example:

```
[ policy_anything ]
countryName = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName = optional
organizationName = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional
```